# transferring music files

Tags: rhythmbox

I want to import my music library from a flash drive to my rhythmbox and keep them permanently on my HDD. I have tried to import the files from the flash drive to rhythmbox and it seems to work. However, when exit rhythmbox, the music files do not appear in the desktop Music. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, what you need to do is **copy** the files to a folder on your internal hard drive, probably `MUSIC`, then have `Rhythmbox` scan that folder.
You can then disconnect the external drive and voilà, RB will have your music.

Incidentally, my personal preference is Clementine. Bon.